# awk '/^/' empty output (complete command inside)

Tags: printing, awk, grep, cat

```
cat /path/to/file  | awk '{if ('/^TCF/' || '/^FSTL/' ) print $0;}' > /path/to/output.txt
```

Hi! 
This produces an empty output, however it does work on a "textedit document", but not this "Plain text document". Other than that, its no different, only that it does not work.

```
cat /path/to/file  | awk '{if ($3=="TCF1" || $3=="FSTL7T2" || $3=="GLI3") print $0;}'
```

This one works fine, but I want all names starting with TCF, not only TCF1.

Please help!

Comment: When you do a test within an `if` statement you need to tell what to test. Change `/^TCF/` to `$0~/^TCF/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
cat /path/to/file  | awk '{if ('/^TCF/' || '/^FSTL/' ) print $0;}' > /path/to/output.txt
```

you can use

```
awk '/^TCF/ || /^FSTL/' /path/to/file > /path/to/output.txt
```

Note `'/^TCF/'` is wrong, it should be only `/^TCF/`. Also, avoid using `cat` as the file can be given as a parameter to `awk`. Finally, `print $0` is the default action of `awk`, so you can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
awk '/^TCF/||/^FSTL/' /path/to/file  >output.txt
```

The problem with your statement is:

```
awk '{if ('/^TCF/' || '/^FSTL/' ) print $0;}'
```

should be:

```
awk '{if ($0~/^TCF/ || $0~/^FSTL/ ) print $0;}'
```

Comment: The `$0~` is implied, so unnecessary, even inside the block like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! It help me to solve it, but I ended up with the following:

cat /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 | awk '{if ($3~/^TCF/ || $3~/^GLI/) print $0;}' > /path/to/test1.txt

But, do you know how to:

1. Include the first row in file1 in the test1.txt output?
2. And, is it possible to include if TCF and GLI came from file1 or file2?